# Access SQL subquery WHERE clause doesn't filter results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with a query in an Access database. The database would be for storing and managing basic statistics of a sportsleague.
This is my query string:

```
SELECT Participants.Name AS Name
, Count(Games.Participants) AS NumberOfGames
, (

     SELECT Name
     , Count(Games.Winner)
     FROM Participants
     INNER JOIN Games
          ON Participants.ID = Games.Winner
     WHERE Participants.ID = Games.Winner

   ) AS Won
FROM Participants
INNER JOIN Games 
     ON Participants.ID = Games.Participants.Value
GROUP BY Participants.Name
ORDER BY Participants.Name;
```

For some reason, the subquery returns the number of all records, not just the ones where the ID of the winner matches with the ID of the participant, and I can't figure out why. The content of the subquery works when it isn't in a subquery. And when I explicitly state the ID of a participant in the WHERE clause of the subquery, it returns correct value for that ID. But I can't make it work the way I need it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your query makes no sense and will not run in MS Access (or any other database).

Comment: Your subquery `WHERE` doesn't make sense. You've got a `JOIN` that matches the two tables on `Participants.ID = Games.Winner`, which returns all rows where the two values match, followed by a `WHERE Participants.ID = Games.Winner`, which again returns all rows where the two values match. I don't think that's what you intend. Sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data would be needed in order to help.

Comment: @KenWhite My problem is no matter how I ``JOIN`` or how I state the ``WHERE`` clause it always returns every single record from the Games table.

Comment: As I said, we're not going to be able to help you without sample data and output. You've not provided the necessary information yet. Using a useless WHERE clause that mimics what the JOIN already does isn't going to be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correlate your subquery with the outer query - at present your subquery has no connection and so returns results for all participants. Without sample data it's hard to be certain but this should work:

```
SELECT Participants.Name AS Name, 
       Count(Games.Participants) AS NumberOfGames,
       (SELECT Count(Winner)
        FROM Games 
        WHERE Games.Winner = Participants.ID) AS Won
FROM Participants
INNER JOIN Games ON Participants.ID = Games.Participants.Value
GROUP BY Participants.Name
ORDER BY Participants.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you'll want to use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    p.name as name, 
    count(*) as numberofgames, 
    sum(iif(g.winner = p.id,1,0)) as won
from 
    participants p inner join games g on p.id = g.participants
group by 
    p.name
order by 
    p.name
```

Here `p` & `g` are merely aliases to save typing out the table names repeatedly.

Comment: To the downvoters: this is probably correct.  Access SQL works a bit differently than ANSI SQL does.